# Postgres: Immediate constraint evaluation order in CTEs with multiple Insert / data-modifying statements

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, common-table-expression, check-constraints

I'm confused by what is documented in Postgres' documentation in terms of data-modifying CTEs vs what I see in practice. I'm on Postgres 13.

Postgres' docs state the following about [data-modifying expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, **the order** in which the specified updates actually happen **is unpredictable**. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), so **they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables.** ...that **RETURNING** data is **the only way to communicate changes** between different WITH sub-statements and the main query

For a CTE with multiple data-modifying-sub-statement expressions, I interpret this as stating that there's no guaranteed order that the statements will run in. Furthermore, if the sub-statements are dependent on one another then only data from a `returning` clause will be passed along as a dependency. Since the actual target table data cannot be seen, if these dependent sub-statements must also satisfy mutual foreign key constraints or triggers, those constraints will be unsatisfiable since the "target table"'s data which would satisfy the constraint cannot be seen.

However, this interpretation seemed flawed when I tested it, as demonstrated below.

Given the following example tables

```sql
create table parents (
    parent uuid not null,
    primary key (parent)
);

create table children (
    child uuid not null,
    parent uuid not null,
    primary key (child),
    foreign key (parent) references parents on delete cascade
);
```

where `children` has a foreign key reference to `parents`, and by default this fk is evaluated immediately, I perform the following data-modifying CTE expression:

```sql
with new_parents as (
    insert into parents (parent)
    values (gen_random_uuid())
    returning *
),
new_children as (
    insert into children (child, parent)
    select gen_random_uuid(), new_parents.parent
    from new_parents
    returning *
)
select * from new_children;
```

To my surprise the foreign key was not violated and I received the following output:

```sql
                child                 |                parent                
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 82754b4d-aacc-4d2a-863d-8759602f1e42 | 03be209a-6e67-44d9-9210-b20495bb789f
```

I expected it to violate the foreign key constraint, because the fk references the `parents` table, *not* the data from `returning *` which by Postgres' docs is the only way to communicate data between sub-statements in the same CTE.

Please explain where my interpretation is wrong, what actually happens behind the scenes, and where this is documented so I can leverage data-modifying CTEs consistently and correctly.

Comment: Your "because" argument for what you expected doesn't follow either description of the update semantics, so it's not clear what your reasoning is. PS The updates to the base tables don't have a prescribed order. But they could happen in an OK order. But anyway other than the update times the CTE evaluations do have an order because the 2nd uses the 1st. PS Do you have justification that the get_randoms return different values? And what happens when you use specific values?

Comment: > Your "because" argument for what you expected doesn't follow either description of the update semantics, so it's not clear what your reasoning is -- 

You'll need to provide your own interpretation of what is documented to clarify for me what you're stating here.

Comment: >anyway other than the update times the CTE evaluations do have an order because the 2nd uses the 1st -- 

Please provide documentation that this is true. The documentation that I did provide does imply this by the necessity of the returning statement, but that does not defeat my original point of "returning *" != the actual table.

Comment: > Do you have justification that the get_randoms return different values?
Yes, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html

Comment: > And what happens when you use specific values?

I don't understand how this is relevant to the question, but I tested with specific values as well and the outcome is strictly the same as what is written in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article appears to explain the discrepancy, though I cannot seem to find where this behavior is documented.

https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-08-27-deferrable-sql-constraints.html#cyclic-foreign-keys

The article states that foreign keys are checked *per statement* and CTEs act as 1 statement, therefore the foreign key is not checked in my example until after the CTE has already finished execution.

> Common table expressions (CTEs) allow multiple queries to be considered as the same statement when checking constraints. Since foreign keys are checked per statement this approach works fine.